# date in 'dd-mmm-yyyy' varchar to date type in sql

Tags: mysql, date

I have a date field in my table which is of the type varchar. It's in the format '15-jul-2015'.  I want to convert it to date type in sql. The other questions where I looked for an answer didn't have answers to my perticular case. If the answer was there I couldn't find/understand it. I am new to sql and will really appreciate a detailed solution.

Comment: Like nothing in your particular problem really!!!

Comment: The MySQL website has documentation that details how to convert a date string to various formats.

Answer (score 4):

Use `str_to_date`:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('15-jul-2015','%d-%M-%Y');
```

see the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for more informations.

Comment: Thanks. What do I do for converting the entire column?

Comment: @Tyrion SELECT STR_TO_DATE(<column name>,'%d-%M-%Y') from <tablename>;

Comment: Thanks for helping a noob!

Comment: This is genius!